# Animation does not work after the first time to return to the original state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have two UIImages one over another, with the same size (40 by 40) it's a simple dot on the whole UIImage and I want to animate rotating as a 3D. When the first UIImage "colapse" and it is not visible, change the property HIDDEN to YES, and immediately the UIImage under the first begin to appears, and when the user press the button again everything turn back at the first state. But i works only the first time, after that, just appears and disappears the images.

Heres is my code:

```
    @interface ViewController ()
    {
    BOOL myFlag;
    }
    @end


    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.C002.image = [Test imageOfCircle002];
        self.C005.image = [Test imageOfCircle005];
        self.C005.hidden = YES;
        myFlag = YES;
    }



    - (IBAction)animationButton:(id)sender
    {
        if (myFlag)
        {
//First state of the UIImages, 
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                //3D rotation C002
                CABasicAnimation* animation;
                animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
                animation.fromValue = @(0);
                animation.toValue = @(0.5 * M_PI);
                animation.repeatCount = 1;
                animation.duration = 1.0;

                [self.C002.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];

                CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                transform.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0;
                self.C002.layer.transform = transform;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                self.C002.hidden = YES; //Hide the first image 
                self.C005.hidden = NO; //Show the second and animate
                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                    //3D rotation C005
                    CABasicAnimation* animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
                    animation2.fromValue = @(0.5 * M_PI); //begin where the first UIImage ends
                    animation2.toValue = @(1.0 * M_PI);
                    animation2.repeatCount = 1;
                    animation2.duration = 1.0;

                    [self.C005.layer addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"rotation"];

                    CATransform3D transform2 = CATransform3DIdentity;
                    transform2.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0;
                    self.C005.layer.transform = transform2;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [self.C002.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotation"];
                    [self.C005.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotation"];
                }];

            }];
            myFlag = NO; // Set the flag to other state. 
        }
        else
        { //Heres try to turn everything back, but... not working. 
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                //3D rotation C005

                CABasicAnimation* animation;
                animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];
                animation.fromValue = @(1.0 * M_PI); //begin where is in the last animation
                animation.toValue = @(0.5 * M_PI);
                animation.repeatCount = 1;
                animation.duration = 1.0;

                [self.C005.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rotation"];

                CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                transform.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0;
                self.C005.layer.transform = transform;
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                self.C005.hidden = YES;
                self.C002.hidden = NO;

                [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                    //3D rotation C002
                    CABasicAnimation* animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.y"];

                    animation2.fromValue = @(0.5 * M_PI);
                    animation2.toValue = @(0 * M_PI);
                    animation2.repeatCount = 1;
                    animation2.duration = 1.0;

                    [self.C002.layer addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"rotation"];

                    CATransform3D transform2 = CATransform3DIdentity;
                    transform2.m34 = 1.0 / 500.0;
                    self.C002.layer.transform = transform2;
                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [self.C002.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotation"];
                    [self.C005.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"rotation"];
                }];

            }];
            myFlag = YES;
        }

    }
```

Hope guys, you can help me.